# Confuse in fopen() function options read bianry and read text

Tags: c, file, file-io

here i am confused about `fopen("filename.txt","rb")` and `fopen("filename.txt","r")`

So which use when i want to get idea about in this in detail

Comment: @downvoter why are you give down vote. i am new on stack overflow and i am beginner of C programming language stack overflow help us. so why are you giving down vote. make it close this question if it is duplicate

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but it's a question which does not fit so well with the [so faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). It is very open ended with no real answer. I'm surprised it has not had close votes too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the man page for `fopen()` you'll find:

> The mode string can also include the letter 'b' either as a last character or  as  a  character  between  the characters  in any of the two-character strings described above.  This is strictly for compatibility with C89 and has no effect; the 'b' is ignored on all POSIX conforming systems, including Linux.  (Other  systems  may treat  text  files  and  binary  files  differently, and adding the 'b' may be a good idea if you do I/O to a binary file and expect that your program may be ported to non-Unix environments.)

Answer (score 0):

This basically is a matter for the environment you're running in. Environments are allowed to modify data under certain circumstances in non-binary mode and even in binary mode (though in a much more limited manner).

The C standard has this to say about the two types, from C99 `7.19.2 Streams` (my bold):

> 2/ A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into lines, each line
>   consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character. Whether the
>   last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined.
>
> **Characters may have to be added, altered, or deleted on input and output to conform to differing conventions for representing text in the host environment. Thus, there need not be a one-to-one correspondence between the characters in a stream and those in the external
>   representation.**
>
> Data read in from a text stream will necessarily compare equal to the data
>   that were earlier written out to that stream **only if: the data consist only of printing
>   characters and the control characters horizontal tab and new-line; no new-line character is
>   immediately preceded by space characters; and the last character is a new-line character.
>   Whether space characters that are written out immediately before a new-line character
>   appear when read in is implementation-defined.**
>
> 3/ A binary stream is an ordered sequence of characters that can transparently record
>   internal data. **Data read in from a binary stream shall compare equal to the data that were
>   earlier written out to that stream, under the same implementation. Such a stream may,
>   however, have an implementation-defined number of null characters appended to the end
>   of the stream.**

So, basically, if you want to maximise the chances of your data not being modified, use binary mode. If you're following the rules for text mode, you can use that without fear.